# Same word fills all the blanks

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Inspired by the famous puzzle (origin unknown to me)

> Fill in the blanks in the following sentence using the same word OR its split versions (not anagrams).
>
> A _____ surgeon, was _______ to operate on his patient because there was
>   _____.

My version: Fill in the blanks in the following sentences using the same word or its split versions (no anagrams)

> Detective Inspector Susan Collins thought ______, the butler, _______. It ______, the _______.

The word/s (and its split versions), in the above sentence could be dictionary words, acceptable slangs, names, proper nouns etc. No anagrams. There are no repeated words in my answer

The answer to the famous original puzzle

> Notable, Not able, and No Table

Comment: Are standard abbreviations / acrnoyms allowed as part of the answer ?

Comment: No abbreviations or acronyms in my answer but if you have an innovative answer thta would be interesting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically  R  Dye has got the answer. My answer (as Rubio pointed out) has 4 difffernt word versions

> Detective Inspector Collins thought, **W A Sherman**, the butler, **was her man**. It **was Herman**, the **washerman**.

Of course R  Dye deserves credit.

Answer (score 42):

> Detective Inspector Susan Collins thought **Washerman**, the Butler, **was her man**. It **was Herman**, the **washerman**.

Comment: I suspect the first case should look something more like N. O. Body, rather than what you have.

Comment: Wow Rubio. Very astute

Answer (score 4):

Not as good as the top answer, but perhaps notable:

> Detective Inspector Susan Collins thought **I. S. Suer**, the butler, **is suer**. It **is Sue R.**, the **issuer**.

Comment: ZX9  Gramatically it should read " is THE suer"?

Comment: @DEEM Agreed, this answer has rather informal grammar. I think "suer" is already a less-than-preferable word, though it appears in Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps, it could be (of many other possibilities)

> Wasman,

As,

> Detective Inspector Susan Collins thought *Wasman*(a proper noun, for the surname of a person) , the butler, **was**  **man**. It *was*, the *man*.

Comment: The last bit doesn’t work. It needs to be the whole word not half of it

Comment: Correct Beastly Gerbil