# Same word fills all the blanks (2)

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, humor

As a follow up to

[Same word fills all the blanks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/55835/5373)

The same word or its split versions (no anagrams) fills all the blanks in the stanza below. I've taken slight liberty with grammar.

> Poor old Andy  ______
>
> His ___ __ a sharp edged  ______
>
> A bit of bruise and sprain
>
> ___ ____ of throbbing pain

Comment: Is the double quote intentional?

Comment: Sorry No. I am still not used to some of  the fonts related stuff

Comment: Is the double underscore intentional?

Comment: Yes. Just another hint I guess

Comment: no one ever solved the original one in your link?

Comment: As I mentioned there one answer was very close so I posted my own answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this is...

> **Button**

Because...

> Poor old Andy **Button**,
>  His **butt on** a sharp edged **button**.
>  A bit of bruise and sprain,
>  **But ton** of throbbing pain!

Ouch! :)

Answer (score 12):

How about this?

> Poor old Andy  **Handspoke** 
>  His **hands poke** a sharp edged  **handspoke** 
>  A bit of bruise and sprain 
>  **Hand spoke** of throbbing pain