# Inner and outer space

Tags: word, wordplay, science

<sub>An entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41 : Short and Sweet.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet)</sub>

> On aliens and mediums, the mathematician _______ said,
>
> 'There is __ _____ and __ __', __ scientific view did not accept them.

<sub>Inspiration from DEEM's : [Same word fills all the blanks (2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks-2)</sub>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The mathematician is

> Emmy NOETHER

who said (at least according to the puzzle)

> "There is NO ETHER and NO ET" -- HER scientific view did not accept them.

Comment: Whoa... That's just I was about to say. Brilliant ;D