# The same word (I think) over and over?

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

I saw a man seemingly lost

Me: Hi. Are you looking for something?

Him:    ____ .

Me:     Go to the Federal Triangle ____ street.

Him:    Do you know the address?

Me:     I think it is ____ street.

Him:    O yeah. The Federal building with the IRS office.

Me:     Yes. It also houses a HUD office, an FBI office and ____ office

Him:    Thanks

Fill in the blanks with one or two words.

Hint

> Think of a 3 letter word - it is in the MW dictionary.

Linked to

[Same word fills all the blanks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55835/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks)

Comment: So, I have an answer that requires that you are wrong about the street name by several blocks..

Comment: Are the rules the same as the linked puzzle?

Comment: @DrD - Is there a typo in the sentence "It also houses a HUD office, an FBI office and ____ office;" specifically, after *and*, shouldn't there by an *a/an/the*, or is the article a part of the blank to be filled in?

Comment: @marsnebulasoup the blanks are correct. You will see that after the answer is posted. The rules are similar to the linked puzzle but ------

Comment: Several blocks @Bass?  I wonder how.

Comment: @DrD - I'm curious what you mean by "It also houses a HUD office, an FBI office and ____ office." It seems like you're referring to the "Federal building with the IRS office" but as far as I can tell, rot13(gurer nera'g nal ohvyqvatf (va QP ng yrnfg) gung unir obgu n UHQ naq SOV bssvpr jvguva gurz)...

Comment: It could e.g. be the _street_ that has all of them. Though I had a quick look and it didn't look to me as if there was any such street.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but there isn't any street that has them all...except maybe rot13(9gu Fg Rkcerffjnl/9gu Fg AJ, orpnhfr vg tbrf cnfg obgu n UHQ naq SOV bssvpr, gubhtu arvgure ner grpuavpnyyl ba vg)...see [here](https://i.gyazo.com/a2ebc7d1fccb49f9286715b8d7d29c73.jpg)...or maybe rot13(R Fgerrg)?...[map](https://i.gyazo.com/b83838c7d0e3dea3317bf353c8220d2b.jpg)

Comment: I never said DC anywhere. Please do not focus on that. Does it have to be an actual place? And there are many cities where a single Federal building houses different offices.

Comment: @DrD You say "federal triangle" though, which implies DC...if it is not a real place, then what is the `knowledge` tag for?

Comment: Not everyone globally knows what a HUD or IRS is for example. rot13 Naq yrg'f fnl gur nafjre vf NOPQRS. Vg svgf bgure pyhrf avpryl ohg abg guvf bssvpr pyhr. Fb bar jvyy unir gb svaq bhg vs NOPQR svgf gur bssvpr pyhr, evtug?

Comment: @DrD - If the answer is, say, ABCDEF, and can be split into, let's say, AB and CDEF, can a blank be filled with these words, but not in order, like "CDEF AB," (instead of "AB CDEF"), or even just one of the two (or more?) words ABCDEF is split into, like just "AB" for one blank and "ABC DEF" for another?

Comment: In this case please see the title. The same word over and over. So fnzr jbeq be vgf fcyvg irefvbaf nf jryy nf ubzbcubarf pbhyq svg urer. Cyrnfr frr guvf chmmyr nyfb https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks-2

Comment: @DrD so does [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks-2) mean that the sentences aren't necessarily grammatically correct, like in the other puzzle like you gave? Because if they are grammatically correct, wouldn't it mean that --

Comment: rot13(gur nafjre jbhyq unir gb fgneg jvgu rvgure na "n" "na" be "gur," sbyybjrq ol gur bssvpr anzr, va gur bssvpr fragrapr? Bgurejvfr vg'q fbhaq njxjneq VZB. Ohg gur fragrapr oynax va "V guvax..." jbhyq frrzf yvxr n fgerrg nqqerff, jvgu gur sbezng "Oyqt_Ahzore + Fgerrg_Anzr," naq vs gur jbeq fgnegf jvgu n n/na/gur, gura gurer pna'g or n ahzore va gung fragnapr, orpnhfr gurer nera'g nal ahzoref (va ratyvfu) gung fgneg jvgu n, na, be gur. Fb V'q thrff gung rvgure gur chmmyr vf tenzzngvpnyyl pbeerpg naq gur "V guvax..." fragrapr oynax qbrf abg fgneg jvgu n ahzore be vg vfa'g.)

Comment: @marsnebulasoup Very astute comment. I think the puzzle is conversationally ( and gramatically) correct. I will post a clear hint tomorrow.

Comment: @DrD Most people know what a HUD is. Its a Head Up Display....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me: Hi. Are you looking for something?

> Him: ATM.
>  Me: Go to the Federal Triangle at M street.

Him: Do you know the address?

> Me: I think it is 80 M street.

Him: O yeah. The Federal building with the IRS office.

> Me: Yes. It also houses a HUD office, an FBI office and a TM office, you know, where they do trademarks or was it the Toyota Motors HQ, I can never remember...

Him: Thanks

> Me: Nice puzzle!

Comment: Not sure if this would work because the OP said no acronyms in the question they linked for the rules

Comment: @marsnebulasoup, it says no anagrams. Acronyms seem to be acceptable.

Comment: @MacGyver88 - In the comments under the question it says so

Comment: Not true @marsnebulasoup. ATM is a word in MW dictionary.https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atm. Also linking does not necessarily require exact same rules. I think I said similar but....

Comment: BTW.  TM is indeed a Trade Mark. US does have  TM office.

Comment: @DrD ...so are acronyms allowed then?

Comment: Yes, in this puzzle's context.

Answer (score 1):

Could be

> **ONE**

I saw a man seemingly lost
Me: Hi. Are you looking for something?
Him:

> **ONE** .

Me: Go to the Federal Triangle

> **ON E** street.

Him: Do you know the address? 
Me: I think it is

> **ON E** street.

Him: O yeah. The Federal building with the IRS office. 
Me: Yes. It also houses a HUD office, an FBI office and

> **ONE** office

Him: Thanks

Thoughts

> I thought this yesterday but didn't think it long enough. Still seems like a stretch, but the clue says look for a three letter word. So, I jumped on it.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track @MacGyer88. +1  But my answer is different. All 4 blanks come out different

Comment: @DrD, How is that possible with a 3 letter word, using one or two words per blank, and four blanks? Methinks it is not actually a 3-letter word then... Anyway, that's all I have. Thanks.

Comment: That is the fun part. That is why I made this Conversational and not just a gramatically correct single sentence. Fvatyr yrggre fgerrg anzr vf cresrpg guvaxvat.

Comment: If the answer would have been big with quite a number of letters, I would have been a bit convinced. The answer being a $3$ letter word is still not convincing to me.