# Same word fills all the blanks: Part 3

Tags: riddle, word

This puzzle is linked to

[Same word fills all the blanks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55835/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks)

The same word or its split versions fill all the blanks in the folllowing sentence. The rules and other details are explained in the link as well as the subsequent sequel of the same puzzle. Please check it out before you solve this.

> In the country of _____ green state is known as ______ because of the
>   lack of _____ there.

Comment: Do we need to/ can we add punctuation in our splits?

Comment: Yes you can as long as the same spelling appears

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm probably just being silly because the sentence doesn't make much sense this way, but how about:

> In the country of **Oz, one** green state is known as **O-Zone** because of the lack of **ozone** there.
>
>  [Though I guess it *could* make sense if this is *man-made* ozone (AKA smog), so that zone then has more Oxygen (O) to breathe.]

Comment: guvax bs Bmbar Cbyyhgvba @Walt

Comment: @DEEM OK, didn't think of that (added). Thanks for that, my plan B was somehow trying to connect it all to the [Numa Numa song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-Zone)... ;)