# Same word fills all the blanks (again)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

This puzzle is linked to

[Same word fills all the blanks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55835/same-word-fills-all-the-blanks)

and its sequels. Some creative thinking is required.

In the following sentence, fill in the blanks using the same word or its split versions (no anagrams). One blank is a homophone.

> In the book club meeting __ __ __ with a comment that once the famous
> British novelist A__ _____ the word ________ as “_______”.

Each blank line is a word or part of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that resolves this fairly nicely, I think...

> *In the book club meeting **MISS PEL LED** with a comment that once the famous British novelist [A**MIS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsley_Amis) **SPELLED** the word **MISSPELLED** as “**MISSPELT**”.*
>
>  The use of 'MISSPELT' in the last word is pertinent to the novelist in question being British, since this alternative spelling is widely used outside of American English. (Although the OP may equally be seeking the use of 'MISPELLED' here, which is a common way to *misspell* 'MISSPELLED'! Either way, I believe the use of an alternative spelling or misspelling of this 'same word' in the last instance is a deliberate joke intended to break the usual format for this puzzle type!)

Comment: How about rot 13 (zvff cryyrq zvff cryyrq, juvpu npghnyyl unccraf gb or n ynfg anzr [yvax](https://collive.com/dee-dee-pelled-66-obm/) )

Comment: Agree with everything you said @Stiv. Great solve.